# Judges vs kings

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between judges and kings in the OT? I understand that judges judged disputes between people; but, I have finally started reading the Bible cover to cover and am shocked at the warring and land acquisition they were into.  So  what is the difference?

Comment: If you are shocked by the wars the Judges got into, wait until you get to the Kings.

Comment: But did judges simply act as kings with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest differences between a King and an Old Testament Judge: once a royal dynasty has started then the next king is chosen by the previous king. On the other hand each one of the Judges was chosen directly by God.  This in effect means that each Judge was chosen for upon their own merit, or godliness.

Answer (score 0):

Judges were leaders appointed by God to deliver people from times of crisis. The kings were established because the people wanted one as seen in 1 Samuel 8.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).